# How should I add a link to websites hosted on a server?

Tags: apache-2.2

So our marketing team has decided to launch a promotional offer to provide free hosting to small business owners. The only cliche is to provide a link in the footer towards our website.
The user can host their own websites
What is the best way to ensure that link is always present in the footer?
Anything that can be done using apache mod rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

This used to be the model for many free hosts in the past. On a technological basis, it's a war the user will generally win - they can hide it with JavaScript, CSS, HTML comments, etc.

Generally, the best way to ensure this is the threat of having the free hosting revoked if the link goes away. Check periodically, but you probably shouldn't be offering access to your servers if you don't trust the clients anyways.